# Angular Js- Why on click the value is not selected?

Tags: angularjs, dropdown, typeahead

I am implementing a typeahead with an image in the dropdown the problem is when i click the item in the dropdown it does not get selected.

```
<body ng-app="TypeaheadDemo">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
    <a>
      <img ng-src="{{match.model.img}}" width="16"> {{match.model.name}}
    </a>
  </script>

  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <h1>Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="query" class="form-control" typeahead="name as result.name for result in results | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" />
  </div>
</body>

    angular.module("TypeaheadDemo", ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('TypeaheadCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.results = [{
      name: "California",
      img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/45px-Flag_of_California.svg.png"
    }, {
      name: "Delaware",
      img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c6/Flag_of_Delaware.svg/45px-Flag_of_Delaware.svg.png"
    }, {
      name: "Florida",
      img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg/45px-Flag_of_Florida.svg.png"
    }];
  }]);
```

Here is the link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pqe3pf89/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is being built incorrectly, you can use `select as` if you like but not that way. The way you are doing so, is selecting nothing to your model.

To get your code working you can change your expression to look like the code bellow: it will select `result.name` as the value of your `ngModel` and will filter your list by the property `name` of your `result` item value using the `$viewValue`.

```
typeahead="result.name for result in results | filter:{name: $viewValue}"
```

Answer (score 1):

@Lenilson de Castro is correct, but that will only bind `$scope.query` to the selected result's name property... that is "California", "Florida", ...

If you would like to bind `$scope.query` to the complete result object, you can use:

```
typeahead="result as result.name for result in results | filter:{name: $viewValue}"
```